# AspectJ Can't run @Before advice

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Good day developers.

I just started to learn about AspectJ AOP style. 
Please help me. I'm trying to learn about LTW(load time weaving) because I more interest of nested method invokation with AspectJ and have code like:

package pkg.aop.target;

```
public class AppOut {


    public void methodOutside() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Invoking AppOut.methodOutside()");  

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        methodInside();

       }


   public void methodInside() {



       System.out.println("Invoking AppOut.methodInside()");

        }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AppOut().methodOutside();

    }

}
```

And aspect part:

```
package pkg.aop.myaspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(* *.*(..))")
    void anyCallToMethod() {
    }


    @Before("anyCallToMethod()")
    public void beforeLogicAspect() {

        System.out.println("Should invoke before every method from AppOut class.");

    }

}
```

In my JVM args in eclipse i have:

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\Vadim\workspace\aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar
```

When I run I can't see any before method invocation advice running, just see my method messages. What I do wrong??

My output is:

```
Invoking AppOut.methodOutside()
Invoking AppOut.methodInside()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your pointcut to

```
call(* *(..))
```

Comment: Now I have @Pointcut("call(* *(..))") but it did not change situation. I still can't see advice method before. Is it ok if my Aspect and my AppOut class in diferent packages?

Comment: Right. I wasn't paying attention to that. Sorry. The pointcut seems fine then. How do you compile this? Maven?

Comment: I did not compile it. I just run in from Eclipse and expacting to see it working? Do I have to compile it?

Comment: I'm not certain what Eclipse does. It's clear that the aspect code isn't woven into your code. How exactly do you run this in Eclipse?

Comment: Just regular way. Click "green button with white triangle inside" on the top of menu. Like I would run any simple apps in Eclipse

Comment: and you have eclipse's AspectJ plugin installed?

Comment: yes. I have spring tools suite. It's has all I need

Comment: In that case, please update your question with the output from within Eclipse when you compile and run. This should indicate if the weaving process is happening and if any join point is discovered.

Comment: Is that from your console?

Comment: I was expecting to see compile output. What about AJDT's console? From the "console" view, select AJDT console.

Comment: Hey I don't realy understand what is javaagent for. I don't have it in my jdk_1.7.45\bin\ folder. With Spring AOP everythings works fine. But I need AspectJ. Please tell me how can I have compile out

Answer (score 0):

```
pointcut anyCallToMethod(): execution(public void *(..) ) ;
```

Comment: Sir Where I have to put it? I don't have aspect class I have common java class. How it will work

Comment: Oh sry, and using execution instead of call does not bring the right behavior ?